# Profiled application started too soon

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, visualvm, jvisualvm

When I try to perform the application startup profiling getting `Profiled application started too soon` have attached error message screenshot below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ywTW.png]

This warning shows after I forcibly killed a previously profiled application. Have restarted my system but still shows that warning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After analysing the visualvm source code, there is a file (`${user.home}/.nbprofiler/5140`) which will be create by visualvm on each profiling startup and will deleted at the end of profiling.

In my case due to the previous force killing of application which eventually leaves that file (not deleted) after manual deleting that file it works fine.

Reference links

- [file path](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/blob/0588a4cc9af99d1584f0be4a682be40d9d14386e/visualvm/libs.profiler/profiler/src/org/graalvm/visualvm/lib/profiler/NetBeansProfiler.java#L1563)
- [create on startup](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/blob/5ef9b12a7dc474e08c7580436aa98d5f8b17f52b/visualvm/profiler/src/org/graalvm/visualvm/profiler/ProfilerSupport.java#L259)
- [delete on exit](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/blob/0588a4cc9af99d1584f0be4a682be40d9d14386e/visualvm/libs.profiler/profiler/src/org/graalvm/visualvm/lib/profiler/NetBeansProfiler.java#L877)